# Assign value to hash argument on condition

Tags: ruby

I have a ActiveRecord backend model where I am inserting records. However when I am assigning value to certain attributes i would like to assign them based on a certain condition being satisified or not. How can I go about doing it? Have attached an example below for better sake of clarity.

```
@user = User.find_by_name("John")

Store.create(
  name: "Some Store",
  email: "store@example.com",
  user_id: @user.id if @user.applicant?
)
```

Comment: `user_id: (@user.id if @user.applicant?)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can't apply suffix `if` to keyword arguments / hash elements this way. I normally do something along these lines:

```rb
store_params = {
  name: "Some Store",
  email: "store@example.com",
}
store_params[:user_id] = @user.id if @user.applicant?

Store.create(store_params)
```

This also works well if there's an existing user_id value that needs to be preserved if `@user` is not an applicant. For example, when you're updating records. For creation, simple parenthesizing should work, as pointed out by others

```
user_id: (@user.id if @user.applicant?)
```

Caveat: this assumes that the default value for user_id is nil, so a nil produced from the expression when user is not an applicant is equal to the value set when user_id was not supplied at all.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer as this is more of a clean way to me and also avoids potential falltraps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [safe-operator](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) here

Just use brackets to avoid interpreter error

```
Store.create(
  name: "Some Store",
  email: "store@example.com",
  user_id: (@user.id if @user&.applicant?)
)
```

Comment: I don't think they're trying to work around `@user` possibly being nil. It's something else.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, may be. But this place is potential error